# Error in C program that I don't understand

Tags: c

I just started out learning C with "The C Programming Language" book. I have an experience in programming mainly in python so I'm not new and I usually understand errors and fix them, but this time I really don't understand what's wrong with the C program that I just copied from the book to get some practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /*Maximum input of the line size*/

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/*Print longest input line*/
int main()
{
    int len; //Current line size 
    int max; //The max lenght seen so far 
    char line[MAXLINE]; //Current input line 
    char longest[MAXLINE]; //longest line saved here 

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) //There was a line
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s and return its lenght */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume 'to' is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

**And here is the error message:**

```
error: conflicting types for 'getline'
```

Comment: `getline` is already a function in `stdio.h`, see `man getline`. Simply name your function something else.

Comment: You are right, Thank you.

Comment: I was *really* *annoyed* when Posix went and standardized their `getline`.  I'd been using my own `getline` for ~30 years, ever since I read about it in K&R.  Took me years to clean 'em all up.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is (now) a standard POSIX library function (defined in `<stdio.h>`).  Your function has the same name and is thus clashing with it.

**The solution is to simply change the name.**

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it.

Comment: A proper solution is to move the C implementation closer to a standard C implementation by including `-D_ANSI_SOURCE` in the compilation options.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — which standard specifies that `-D_ANSI_SOURCE` brings the compilation more in line with standard C, and how does it interact with `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`, `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`, `-D_GNU_SOURCE` and other related macros?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Admittedly, I do not have a source. It is something I have known for a while, but the [GNU C Library feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros) do not show it. They do not show any setting for disabling or excluding certain features, but defining `_POSIX_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` as `0` seem to do the trick in Apple tools.